# Why constraints are updated on scrolling of UITableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout

I have 2 simple UILabel that needs to be placed horizontally. One of them on right side of view, while second one is on the left side and gets all possible space. Here is my constraints:

```
    amountOfQuestions.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor, constant: -8).isActive = true
    amountOfQuestions.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor).isActive = true


    topicName.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
    topicName.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
    topicName.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -8).isActive = true
    topicName.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: amountOfQuestions.leftAnchor, constant: -8).isActive = true
```

Seems like everything is ok, but when table view is shown, it looks like this:

[image]

But after I scroll couple of times my table up and down, it became normal:

[image]

Why my table is not shown immediately like in second picture?

Solution:

```
amountOfQuestions.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor, constant: -8).isActive = true
    amountOfQuestions.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    amountOfQuestions.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .horizontal)
    amountOfQuestions.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.required, for: .horizontal)

    topicName.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
    topicName.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
    topicName.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -8).isActive = true
    topicName.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: amountOfQuestions.leftAnchor, constant: -8).isActive = true
    topicName.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .horizontal)
    topicName.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.required, for: .vertical)


    let myBottom = topicName.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -8)
    myBottom.priority = UILayoutPriority(rawValue: UILayoutPriority.required.rawValue - 1)
    myBottom.isActive = true
```

Comment: Where do you set your constraints? Also note that the bottom constraint should have priority set to `999` (not required but high priority) and you need to set vertical hugging priority and compression resistance priority on the left label to 1000 (required). And you have to set horizontal hugging priority and compression resistance for the right label. If you don't do that, then the label content won't be taken into account correctly.

Comment: Thanks. I showed in question how I set constraints. But, why those constraints you told are needed? How they solve problem? Why it is not possible to achieve a goal without using them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple problems that can affect the layout and make it incorrectly defined:

1. Never constrain content to the cell itself. Always constrain to the `contentView` of the cell, e.g.:

   ```
   amountOfQuestions.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.rightAnchor, constant: -8).isActive = true
   ```

(make sure you are adding the labels as subviews of the `contentView`, not of the cell itself).

2. If you want the size of the labels to have any effect, you need to set hugging and compression resistance priorities correctly. Otherwise the layout does not have to respect the content:

   ```
   // you want topic name to resize vertically to respect the content
   topicName.setHuggingPriority(.required, for: .vertical)
   topicName.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.required, for: .vertical)

   // you want amount of question to resize horizontally to respect the content
   amountOfQuestions.setHuggingPriority(.required, for: .horizontal)
   amountOfQuestions.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.required, for: .horizontal)
   ```

3. To avoid layout conflicts during the first layout, it's a good idea to give one the of the vertical constraints a slightly lower layout priority:

   ```
   let bottomAnchor = topicName.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -8)
   bottomAnchor.priority = UILayoutPriority(rawValue: UILayoutPriority.required.rawValue - 1)
   bottomAnchor.isActive = true
   ```

Comment: Your first advice with contentView failed. Without contentView is working, with it, it does not work.

Comment: @abay Describe "does not work". Are you adding the labels to the `contentView` using `contentView.addSubview(topicName)`?

Comment: My guilty. Sorry. But can you clarify why contentView needs to be used? What is benefit of it?

Comment: @abay Well, the content view does not have to have the same size as the cell itself. You can see the difference when you add an accessory to the cell. Then the `contentView` gets smaller and if you have content constrained to the cell itself, it will conflict with the accessory. Similar problems will appear in editing mode (e.g. cell delete button) or with swipe actions.

Answer (score 1):

1- UILabels have an intrinsic content value , that means you don't have to specify a width / height for them , so when you place them horizontally like this

> | - lbl1 - lbl2 - |

This causes a constraint ambiguity because autolayout need to know which label to trim when a one content is too bigger that's why you need to set horizontal compression resistance && setHuggingPriority to lbl2 = 1000

2- You need to lower priority of bottom constraint as the cell assumes a fixed height in the begining of layout and that height may conflict with current total height of the vertical content , so you lower it to avoid this conflict